# React view not updating even if the state is changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a HackerNews with reddit.json

I'm fetching the data that's returining an array and i'm storing it in a variable

For the moment in my view i can only acess a fake json data:

```
    results= [
{'author' : Mister1,'url':'http://url1.com','score':400},
{'author' : Mister2,'url':'http://url2.com','score':350},
{'author' : Mister3,'url':'http://url3.com','score':500},
{'author' : Mister4,'url':'http://url1.com','score':456},
]
```

so when i change the topic i want to search in the bar, the state is changing and i'm getting what i want, my problem is the view it's not updating and stying with the old result

The problem i think is comming from my render code :

```
const list = (
      results
      &&
      results[searchKey]
      &&
      results[searchKey].hits
    )    ||  [
{'author' : Mister1,'url':'http://url1.com','score':400},
{'author' : Mister2,'url':'http://url2.com','score':350},
{'author' : Mister3,'url':'http://url3.com','score':500},
{'author' : Mister4,'url':'http://url1.com','score':456},
]
```

even if the result is changing it's stying with the fake json data.

My code : https://codesandbox.io/embed/mqpjrk3loy

Sorry if my question is dumb.

Comment: Not sure what you expect to happen. `results` is an array and `searchKey` is the actual text you searched for. What do expect to get with `results[searchKey]` ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli as soon as i take off results[searchKey] i got this error list.map is not a function.
I'm excepting to render the new array that is sotred in the state

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work. Can you check it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying too set `list` variable as `results[searchKey].hits`, which have the wrong shape with your `this.state.results`

What you really want is this:

`(results && results.results) || HARDCODED_FALLBACK_DATA`

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think it could be the || operator. Have you tried a ternary operator?

```
{results ? results[searchKey].hits : ' // your hardcoded data '}
```

Comment: Tried it not working, i think i ddin't figure out how to access to my state so i can render it

Comment: Your sandbox doesn't seem to work for me. Can you please confirm that when you click onClick={() => this.fetchSearchTopStories(searchTerm) the state is being updated with your axios response?

Comment: yes it's beeing updated but like i said the view is not updating

Comment: then definitely there is something wrong with your code:
`results
      &&
      results[searchKey]
      &&
      results[searchKey].hits`